# Accessing a Static Resource dynamically from a Lightning Web Runtime site

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwr

### How can I access the contents of a static resource dynamically when running in an LWR site?

I have a JSON configuration file that I need to access from multiple components (including Visualforce, Aura and LWC flavors).

Accessing a static resource using an `XMLHttpRequest` is how I've typically done this in the past, and I've never run into a major issue doing so.

However, I've recently run into a problem when trying to access a JSON static resource from an LWR (Lightning Web Runtime) site. It seems as though the CSP restrictions apply to my own static resources, which seems overly strict. I get the error message:

> `Lightning Web Security: Cannot request disallowed endpoint: https://myorg.live-preview.salesforce-experience.com/mylwrsite/webruntime/org-asset/9602d40300/resource/0814w000001Dvwd`

<sub>**Note:** This error message has been slightly altered to obscure the actual URL</sub>
[image: A screenshot demonstrating the error message]

I tried adjusting the Security Level to **Relaxed CSP**, thinking that perhaps the Strict CSP was designed to prevent access to all static resources, but it made no difference.

[image: A screenshot demonstrating that Relaxed CSP is enabled for this site]

The only way to make this work is to completely disable Lightning Web Security, which seems like an extreme option.

[image: A screenshot demonstrating that Lightning Web Security is disabled]

---

## Minimal/Complete/Reproducible Example

I've created a simple repro to demonstrate the problem.

> Please Note: I am fully aware that I could **embed a JSON file within the LWC component's resources** or put it in an LWC library. As already stated, the static resource is used by my Visualforce and Aura components, and even my LWC components in a standard page. I would strongly prefer to use that single source of truth rather than copy it and then maintain it in separate locations.

### Static Resource

**DefaultTestConfig.resource-meta.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StaticResource xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <cacheControl>Public</cacheControl>
    <contentType>application/json</contentType>
    <description></description>
</StaticResource>
```

**DefaultTestConfig.resource**

```json
{
    "name": "foo",
    "color": "red"
}
```

### LWC Component

**staticResourceTest.js-meta.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>57.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <masterLabel>Static Resource Test</masterLabel>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__UtilityBar</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
    </targets>
    <capabilities>
        <capability>lightningCommunity__RelaxedCSP</capability>
    </capabilities>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

**staticResourceTest.js**

```js
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";
import DefaultTestConfigUrl from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/DefaultTestConfig";

const ERROR_LOAD_CONFIG = "loadConfig";

export default class StaticResourceTest extends LightningElement {
    loading = true;
    name;
    color;
    #errorState;
    get loadConfigError() {
        return this.#errorState === ERROR_LOAD_CONFIG;
    }
    errorMessage;

    async connectedCallback() {
        this.load();
    }

    async load() {
        try {
            let result = await this.getConfig();
            if (typeof result === "string") {
                result = JSON.parse(result);
            }
    
            this.name = result.name;
            this.color = result.color;
            this.loading = false;
        } catch (e) {
            this.#errorState = ERROR_LOAD_CONFIG;
            this.loading = false;
            this.errorMessage = e.message;
        }
    }

    async getConfig() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            try {
                const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                request.open("GET", DefaultTestConfigUrl);
                request.addEventListener("load", () => resolve(request.response));
                request.addEventListener("error", () => reject(Error(request.statusText)));
                request.addEventListener("abort", () => reject(Error(request.statusText)));
                request.send();
            } catch (e) {
                reject(e);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**staticResourceTest.html**

```html
<template>
    <div class="slds-box slds-theme_default">
        <template lwc:if={loading}>
            <lightning-spinner alternative-text="Loading" size="small"></lightning-spinner>
        </template>
        <template lwc:if={loadConfigError}>
            <div class="slds-illustration slds-illustration_small">
                <svg class="slds-illustration__svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <g>
                        <circle cx="16" cy="16" id="BG" r="16" style="fill:#D72828;" />
                        <path d="M14.5,25h3v-3h-3V25z M14.5,6v13h3V6H14.5z" style="fill:#E6E6E6;" />
                    </g>
                </svg>
                <div class="slds-text-longform">
                    <h2 class="slds-text-heading_medium">Unable to load config</h2>
                    <p class="slds-text-body_regular">{errorMessage}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </template>
        <template lwc:else>
            <div class="slds-text-longform">
                <h2 class="slds-text-heading_medium">Name: {name}</h2>
                <p class="slds-text-body_regular">Color: {color}</p>
            </div>
        </template>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Have a look [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/lws-distortion-viewer#XMLHttpRequest_open-value). Looks like "webruntime" is not liked by LWS. I haven't tried your example, but is this URL necessarily the way a static resource is called from a LWR context?

Comment: Thanks @FelixvanHove - I think that exactly describes the error I'm running into. Unfortunately, I don't know how to get around this without building a new AuraEnabled server-side Apex API to just brute-force query the static resource and return the body. That would be an extremely time- and resources-expensive option.

Comment: @FelixvanHove - To answer your question... unfortunately, yes it is. The URL for a static resource in LWR sites has been changed, and the old URL doesn't work. I have a question documenting that issue here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/409187/how-to-get-static-resource-urls-dynamically-in-lwc-that-work-in-lwr-sites

Comment: Wow, I've learned both from your prior and from this question, but have no idea how to work around this.